# When handwriting mathematics, how should I distinguish between $\in$ and $\epsilon$?

Tags: soft-question, notation

Statements such as the definition of a limit use both $\in$ and $\epsilon$. When typed this is easy to distinguish, however when writing them down it is hard for me to differentiate between the two.

I am therefore wondering how you would handwrite these symbols if you had to in order to get around this issue?

Comment: By reading the rest of the statement and understanding the context. In Math, symbols are always meaningless if there is no context. The meaning is always clear in this manner.

Comment: Write epsilon as $\varepsilon$ instead.

Comment: Little epsion you do it as a little manuscript capital E (like a number 3 backwards), whereas the symbol for sets you do it as a  C and then add a little dash in the middle...

Comment: Look at Glyph variants on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon and you find it in form $\varepsilon$ i.e. \varepsilon on mathjax.

Comment: I write $\varepsilon$ `\varepsilon`, not $\epsilon$ `\epsilon`.

Comment: As I went further through school and eventually taught classes, my handwriting for certain letters and digits changed considerably to emphasize differences between things.  Things like including a dash through the digit $7$ (*See [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/62316/does-drawing-a-dash-across-the-numeral-7-seven-increase-legibility)*) or accentuating the "foot" of a $u$ while accentuating a "flag" on a $v$.

Comment: [This post](https://johnkerl.org/doc/ortho/ortho.html) includes many suggestions and explanations for how the author prefers to handwrite things and may be a good read.

Comment: Anyway, when you study ancient Greek, a ‘normal’ epsilon is `ε`. The other, which TeX obtains with the `\epsilon` command, is actually a *lunate* epsilon.

Comment: @JMoravitz That was an interesting read, thank you very much!

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos That should be an answer.

Comment: @JMorawitz: You should make that an answer, so that the link become more visible.

Comment: @Bernard: Not necessarily. When I studied Classical Greek 50+ years ago, we used Crosby & Schaeffer, *An Introduction to Greek*, which uses $\epsilon$. I routinely use that form in mathematics; context invariably prevents confusion with $\in$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: In  France, we always used ε. I had to begin using TeX to discover there existed another epsilon. In my opinion it is the latter which should be called with the \varepsilon command (We used  Allard et Feuillâtre, *Grammaire Grecque*).

Comment: @Bernard: Both forms are old, but $\epsilon$ is older: it appears already as a majuscule in Greek Uncial. That it’s older is not surprising, since it’s closer to the form of the letter in very early Greek alphabets. (Needless to say, I’m perfectly happy with the names as they are!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write $\in$ (`\in`) with two strockes, as a lowercase 'c' followed by a horizontal cross-bar. I write $\varepsilon$ (`\varepsilon`) in one stroke like a backwards $3$.  I tend to avoid the symbol $\epsilon$ (`\epsilon`) entirely. Perhaps the following images will be helpful:

[image]